# Filtering pandas DF by dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas df:

[image]

and want to iterate though a dictionary of filters to isolate the desired row.

For example, filtering on the following should return row:
[image]

```
df =  pd.DataFrame([[10,'A','40%'],
                    [20,'B','20%'],
                    [30,'C','10%'],
                    [40,'D','30%']],
                   columns= ['Col1','Col2','%']) 
dic = {'Col1': 10, 'Col2': 'A'}
```

My current approach is hardcoded to accept just two filter conditions (Col1, Col2) however I need a more generalized approach that can accept N conditions (or a dict of any size).

Comment: 1- please provide the input as DataFrame constructor, 2- how do you want to filter? If **any** or **all** conditions match?

Comment: pd.DataFrame([[10,'A','40%'],
              [20,'B','20%'],
              [30,'C','10%'],
              [40,'D','30%']], columns= ['Col1','Col2','%'])

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Series for automatic alignment and `any` or `all` depending on whether you want any or all conditions True:

```
dic = {'Col1': 10, 'Col2': 'A'}

# we want both Col1 AND Col2 to match
out = df[df[list(dic)].eq(pd.Series(dic)).all(1)]

# we want either Col1 OR Col2 to match (or both)
out = df[df[list(dic)].eq(pd.Series(dic)).any(1)]
```

output:

```
   Col1 Col2    %
0    10    A  40%
```

Comment: The first code snippet with .all(1) was what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't load your pictures but what about this approach?

```py
conditions_dict = {'Col1': 10, 'Col2': 'A'}

def filter_function(row):
    for col, val in conditions_dict.items():
        if row[col] != val:
            return False
    return True

df[df.apply(filter_function, axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try create DataFrame from dict then `merge`

```py
out = pd.DataFrame([dic]).merge(df)
```

```
print(out)

   Col1 Col2    %
0    10    A  40%
```